# Ember-auth signin test fails with json

Tags: testing, asynchronous, ember.js, qunit

I am having some issues with testing my signin/signout and related features of my app. The app works, but the test fail.

For testing, I use a `QUnit` with `testem` (I also tried teaspoon)

```
test "after signin, should redirect user back to previous page", ->
    visit '/library'
    fillIn '.signin-email', 'example@example.com'
    fillIn '.signin-password', 'examplepass'
    click '.signin-btn'
    andThen ->
        equal(testing().path(), 'library', "Should redirect back to library (was #{testing().path()})")
```

After running the test, I get a failure:
([screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/cyJ1hL1) )

```
Authentication: visiting restricted page as non authenticated user: after signin, should redirect user back to previous page (2, 0, 2)Rerun544 ms
{user_id: 2, auth_token: wVveiyDLuXBXu69pQ2XQwg}
Source: 
    at Test.QUnitAdapter.Test.Adapter.extend.exception (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:50149:5)
    at superWrapper [as exception] (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:13374:16)
    at Object.onerror (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:50009:22)
    at onerror (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20453:16)
    at EventTarget.trigger (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20286:22)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20439:14)
    at EventTarget.trigger (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20286:22)
    at http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20588:17
Should redirect back to library (was signin)
Expected:   
"library"
Result: 
"signin"
Diff:   
"library" "signin" 
Source: 
    at http://localhost:7357/public/assets/spec/javascripts/integration/authentication_pages_spec.js.js:22:14
    at andThen (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:50258:20)
    at http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:49817:21
    at isolate (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:49989:14)
    at http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:49972:12
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20463:19)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:7357/public/assets/application-aad0a1b2c887cc25124c361787446e83.js:20513:11)
```

Also, auth.coffee:

```
App.Auth = Em.Auth.extend
  request: 'jquery'
  response: 'json'
  strategy: 'token'
  session: 'cookie'
  modules: [
    'emberData',
    'authRedirectable',
    'actionRedirectable'
  ]

  signInEndPoint: '/signin'
  signOutEndPoint: '/signout'
  tokenKey: 'auth_token'
  tokenIdKey: 'user_id'
  tokenLocation: 'param'
  emberData:
    userModel: 'user'  # create user model on login
  authRedirectable:
    route: 'signin'
  actionRedirectable:
    signInRoute: 'library'
    # signInSmart: true
    # signInBlacklist: ['signin']
    signOutRoute: 'index'
```

I am unable to find the source of the error, so maybe it is something to do with ember-auth. Any ideas would be very appreciated.

### Update 1 [Jan 4th]:

I've written an additional test, which passes only halfway. The test is simpler than the previous in that it does not check a redirect, but only checks that the user name appears in the UI after signin.

```
test "after signin, TEST", ->

    visit '/library'
    fillIn '.signin-email', 'user@example.com'
    fillIn '.signin-password', 'foobargaz'
    click '.signin-btn'
    andThen ->
        ok exists('.menu-signout'), "signout button exists"
```

The assertions passes, but I get an additional error reporting the returned JSON as seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acwS4.png). The screenshot basically shows:

1. [Fail] {user_id: 2, auth_token: wVveiyDLuXBXu69pQ2XQwg}
2. [Pass] signout button exists

Additionally, I've also run the tests by mocking the ajax requests with mockjax, but with the same failure.

Third, I should note that I had to patch "ember-auth-request-jquery.js" to make it work with ember testing as suggested [here](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-request-jquery/pull/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my coffeescript was not the best in the world.

The `module` function in `QUnit` should NOT compile to:

```
module('Authentication: visiting restricted page as non authenticated user', function() {
    return setup(function() {
        return Em.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
    });

});
```

but to:

```
module('Authentication: visiting restricted page as non authenticated user', {
    setup: function() {
        Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
    },
    // This is also new
    teardown: function() {
        App.reset();
    }
});
```

Additionally, in my `spec_helper.coffee` file I had something like this:

```
QUnit.testStart(function() {
    // FIXME: this below made it fail every time
    // Ember.run(function() {
    //   return App.reset();
    // });
    Ember.testing = true;
});

QUnit.testDone(function() {
    Ember.testing = false;
});

QUnit.done(function() {
    return Ember.run(function() {
        return App.reset();
    });
});
```

which seems to have caused some issues, so I just deleted it and the tests now pass.

Comment: To help me find the bug, I created [a small sample app with the same tests](https://github.com/pedrokost/ember_auth_testing_example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're failing to wait on the first visit to happen, so here's how I read it (I'm no CS person)

1. You're telling Ember to go to library
2. Before being sure it's finished navigating you're trying to fill in 2 fields and click a button (all of which probably doesn't exist)
3. then you check to see if it's library, but while waiting after you thought you clicked, really the page finishes rendering the login page from the visit

Here's what js2coffe says it'd kind of look like (my main point is the `then` after the visit).

```
test "after signin, should redirect user back to previous page", ->
  visit("/library").then ->
    fillIn ".signin-email", "example@example.com"
    fillIn ".signin-password", "examplepass"
    click(".signin-btn").then ->
      equal testing().path(), "library", "Should redirect back to library (was " + (testing().path()) + ")"
```

### Update 1/4:  Documentation changed on me

Now we move to educated guess time. Looking through the Ember-auth code it might not be creating any timers/promises that Ember is aware of, in affect Ember thinks it's finished the signin process immediately.  So the click promise is resolved immediately and you run your test immediately (andThen waits on the global testing promise to resolve).  To test the theory you can do some terrible timeout and see if it does indeed redirect after some time

```
test "after signin, should redirect user back to previous page", ->
  visit "/library"
  fillIn ".signin-email", "example@example.com"
  fillIn ".signin-password", "examplepass"
  click ".signin-btn"
  stop()
  Ember.run.later this, (->
    start()
    equal testing().path(), "library", "Should redirect back to library (was " + (testing().path()) + ")"
  ), 5000
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem. Although my code was just like one recommended by the [ember guides on testing](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/#toc_writing-tests), I still tried the _then_ version you proposed without success.

What I find especially curious about this failing test is that QUnit responds with 2 statements:
1. `{user_id: 2, auth_token: wVveiyDLuXBXu69pQ2XQwg}`
2. Should redirect back to library (was signin)

Now I don't see why it would reply with both, and not just the last statement.

Comment: Sorry about that, the documentation changed 2 weeks ago on me, https://github.com/emberjs/website/commit/c5a577a162ad8e221420f4efe4a24626071cd59e#diff-2651cb19f3d8c0961d6deccace214e0c !

Comment: No luck either. What I notice from the test, is that the user gets signed in (I can see that user's name appear in the UI) but the redirect does not happen in the test.
Maybe I should note, that I had to patch "ember-auth-request-jquery.js" to make it work with ember testing as suggested [here](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-request-jquery/pull/1)

Comment: Please, see my last update to the question. I added a similar test which halfway fails. Maybe it gives you some ideas...

Comment: so something is throwing the json as an error? Did you pull down the patched version, or patch and build?  Have you looked up the call stack to see what's throwing it?

Comment: Thanks you for all the help, as it has helped me fix the problem -- see my answer. However, I still have an issue, which is that the tests fail only every second time now. I have opened [a followup question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934995/ember-auth-qunit-tests-fail-every-second-run)